# How do you make bitcoins bought from a exchange anonymous?

Tags: blockchain

Contrary to what most people think, bitcoin is not 100% anonymous. It is pseudonym.

Now, let us say you bought bitcoins from a exchange. The exchange has your government issued ID. Then you send your bitcoins to a offline wallet.

Now, the blockchain has a record of the exchange sending you bitcoins to your wallet, and the exchange has a record of what offline wallet is linked to you.

How do you effectively separate this link?

My theory is that you can send your bitcoins from your offline wallet to a bitcoin casino site, then withdraw your balance to another wallet.

Would that remove all the links to your bitcoins from your ID/make it impossible to trace back to you?

Comment: Bitcoin is anonymous *unless* you do things like buy from an exchange. In practical use, many (not all) purchases require a name and/or a delivery address. [Use Bitcoin with Tor](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-can-i-setup-bitcoin-to-be-anonymous-with-tor).

Comment: What Callerap said is correct. It's pseudonymous. Monero, ZCash and Dash are anonymous, but Bitcoin is pseudonymous.

Comment: Dash isn't more private than Bitcoin. Actually it is less private, because of a smaller user base. Dash PrivateSend is just an implementation of CoinJoin. Better implementations of CoinJoin exists for Bitcoin, for example, ZeroLink (Wasabi Wallet) and JoinMarket.

Answer (score 2):

You should do some mixing transactions in between, I would recommend [Wasabi Wallet](https://www.wasabiwallet.io/) or [JoinMarket](https://github.com/JoinMarket-Org/joinmarket-clientserver). They are both decentralized solutions, where you don't risk loosing your funds, like it is with centralized tumbling services.

Answer (score 0):

What if LE subpoena the Casino,do you fully trust that the Casino won't disclose your records or your IP address?

Even [Bitcoin tumbling services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_tumbler) can't fully separate the link, however with [Cross-Cryptocurrency Tumbling](https://news.bitcoin.com/tumbling-bitcoins-guide-rinse-cycle/) the trails are often so obscured that it becomes impossible or near impossible to trace the origin.
If you want to stay anonymous and leave minimal or obscure the trails, [this is the ultimate guide.](https://www.reddit.com/r/DarkNetMarketsNoobs/wiki/bible/buyer)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot, just go into cash market, you wanna buy in cash and sell in cash, anything bank related and ID related is traceable, read the privacy policy they all report your records per request.